# PHP ini showing errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords, md5

I posted a question about this earlier, but need more help with this as i have narrowed the problem down.  Below is the code i am using.  I am getting two errors, i have also included the lines, but i don't know what the issue is, i am new, please help!

The Code:

```
//Checks if there is a login cookie

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))
    //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page
{ 
    $email = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) 
    {
        if ($pass != $info['password']) 
        {
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
    }
}

//if the login form is submitted 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ // if form has been submitted
  // makes sure they filled it in

    if(!$_POST['email'] | !$_POST['password'])
    {
        die('You did not fill in a required field.');
    }

// checks it against the database

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    }

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'") or die(mysql_error());

    //Gives error if user dosen't exist

    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

    if ($check2 == 0)
    {
        die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
    }

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  
    {
        $_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['password'] = $_POST['password'];

        //gives error if the password is wrong

        if ($_POST['password'] != $info['password'])
        {
            die('Incorrect password, please try again');
        }
        else 
        { 
            // if login is ok then we add a cookie 
            $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']); 
            $hour = time() + 3600; 
            setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['email'], $hour); 
            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);   

            //then redirect them to the members area 

            header("Location: home.php"); 
        } 

    } 

} 
else 
{    
Error # 1:  
    if ($pass != $info['password']) 
Error # 2: 
    if ($_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {
```

Comment: What exactly are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: OT: but you should also consult http://bobby-tables.com/ or read up on mysql_real_escpae_string() - your code seemingly relies on magic_quotes.

Comment: I think i need a new script, can you point me to a reference please.  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you need to test the index before you try to access it ...

Something like

```
if ((isset($info['password'])) && $info['password'] != $pass)
```

OR (though typically looked down upon) suppress the error

```
if (@ $info['password'] != $pass)
```

Comment: Though, that will only fix the symptom (E_NOTICE "errors"), but not the actual problem (incomplete $info[] array due to database mismatch or something).

Comment: That solved the #1 error.  I think i am going to write fresh script.

Comment: I solved it, if you notice in the queries it says SELECT *, instead i tried SELECT email, password